# Nhibernate Session handling in a very high traffic web application

Tags: nhibernate, session-management

I am building a small web application that need to handle 1000 requests per minute.
Each request needs to write one simple row to the database.
I am doing second level cache for the reading.
Can I do session per request in this case? Should I reuse the session? What is the best practice for this kind of situation?
It will be written in C#, SQL SERVER 2008, ASP.NET Generic Handler.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure the session handling will be your problem...

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs , What will be my problem then?

Comment: Well, immediately, I think the strain will be on web server CPU for generating that many dynamic queries so quickly.  I would imagine (and this is totally shooting from the hip) that you would be better served with a lighter-weight `IDbConnection` implementation... perhaps with a prepared statement or a stored procedure.

Comment: What were your findings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session per request should be fine, but you will definitely have to do load testing, as there is no way to predict if your setup will handle the load, or what the bottlenecks will be.